# How to skip separator inclusion in file using awk command

Tags: awk, git-bash

Trying to replace | by , using awk

```
$ awk '{gsub("|",","); print}' sample.txt | tee sample.txt
```

sample file contains ||| characters and target is to replace with ,,, when fired above command the output is ,|,|,| where it should be ,,,

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please post samples of input and expected output in your question to make it clear, thank you.

Comment: sample.txt contains ||| character which I need to replace with ,,,

Comment: You need to escape `|` try like: `awk '{gsub(/\|/,",")} 1' file` once.

Comment: Do not do `cmd file | tee file` or any other variation of trying to write to the same file you're reading while you're reading it for any command as it's not robust. Instead do `tmp=$(mktemp) && cmd file > "$tmp" && mv -- "$tmp" file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `awk '{gsub(/\|/,","); print}' sample.txt | tee output.txt`. Note that "|" need to be escaped with "\", and the result is then "tee"ed to another file. Writing back to the same file may not be safe.

Comment: No need for `| tee`, just `>`.